# git error- did not match any file(s) known to git?

Tags: php, git, git-commit

I have added a pattern to ignore files recursively in exclude file inside .info in .git directory.

```
patter : httpdocs/**/bak_*.*
```

If I commit from httpdocs it is working and from the changed directory it gives error.

```
git commit -m "formatting js" httpdocs/* [working]

git commit -m "formatting js" httpdocs/dir1/dir2/* [giving below error]
```

**error:** pathspec 'httpdocs/dir1/dir2/bak_admin.abc.php' did not match any file(s) known to git.

Basically I want to know why this is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `*` wildcard pattern is expanded by the shell (**not by git**).
That means `git commit -m "formatting js" httpdocs/*` is translated by

```
 git commit -m "formatting js" httpdocs/fileorDir1
 git commit -m "formatting js" httpdocs/fileorDir2
 git commit -m "formatting js" httpdocs/fileorDir3
```

If all those files were already tracked, git commit works. If they are not, the error message you saw is returned.

In the case of `git commit -m "formatting js" httpdocs/dir1/dir2/*`, that is translated as:

```
git commit -m "formatting js" httpdocs/dir1/dir2/fileirDir1
git commit -m "formatting js" httpdocs/dir1/dir2/fileirDir2
git commit -m "formatting js" httpdocs/dir1/dir2/fileirDir3
```

That will include files which are explicitly ignored (not tracked at all), including `bak_admin.abc.php`.
Even if the .gitignore is correctly set, the shell (not git) will pass `bak_admin.abc.php` to the `git commit` command, resulting in

```
error: pathspec 'httpdocs/dir1/dir2/bak_admin.abc.php' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Solution: **do not use '`*`'**

```
git commit -m "formatting js" httpdocs/
git commit -m "formatting js" httpdocs/dir1/dir2/
```

Comment: That's right, but if the `.gitignore` has been set up correctly, git-commit should just ignore those file paths.

Comment: @Vidur No it won't ignore that file, because said file will be passed to git commit explicitly by the shell

Comment: Oops I was mistaken. It does complain about that.

Comment: @Vidur Hence the solution to not use '`*`': let Git figures out which files within a folder it ought to consider. No need for the shell to expand those files.